# Bayesian Question: Exponential Prior and Poisson Likelihood: Posterior?

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, montecarlo

I am needing assistance in a particular question and need confirmation of my understanding.

The belief is that absences in a company follow
a Poisson(λ) distribution.

It is believed additionally that **75% of thes value of λ is less than 5** therefore it is decided that a exponential distribution will be **prior** for λ. You take a random sample of 50 students and find out the number of absences that each has had over the past semester.

The data summarised below, note than 0 and 1 are binned collectively.

**Number of absences**

≤ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

**Frequency**

18 13 8 3 4 3 0 0 0 1

Therefore in order to calculate a posterior distribution, My understanding is that prior x Likelihood which is this case is a Exponential(1/2.56) and a Poisson with the belief incorporated that the probability of less than 5 is 0.75 which is solved using

-ln(1-0.75)/(1/2.56)= 3.5489.

Furthermore a similar thread has calculated the Posterior to be that of a Gamma (sum(xi)+1,n+lambda)

Therefore with those assumptions, I have some code to visualise this

```
x=seq(from=0, to=10, by= 1)
plot(x,dexp(x,rate = 0.390625),type="l",col="red")
lines(x,dpois(x,3.54890),col="blue")
lines(x,dgamma(x,128+1,50+3.54890),col="green")
```

Any help or clarification surround this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think this is more a statistical question and you might get more help here then: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Gamma is [the conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for Poisson so its posterior is a closed-form expression (i.e., simple calculation from data). Since Exponential is a special case of Gamma, try expressing it in Gamma form and use the Gamma-Poisson formulae from [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_discrete_distribution).